# Not able to reference functions in webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundle, es6-modules, webpack-5

I am new to JS library development, and I am trying to do the following

1. Create a library with TypeScript
2. Create a bundle using webpack5
3. Publish the library to npm
4. Use the library in other projects by installing the npm package

I was successful in creating a bundle and uploading it to npm. The problem starts during step 4, when I install the package in a new project. Referencing functions from `functions.ts` does not work. However, when I import the library in `script.js` the code specified in `index.ts` is executed, and I can see the log output. What should I add to `index.ts` in order to be able to reference functions and classes from other files like `functions.ts`? The library will be used by front-end JS files. Thank you for your help in advance!

Project folder structure

```
root
|-dist
|  |-library.js
|
|-scr
|  |-functions.ts
|  |-index.ts
|
|-node_modules
```

I want to use `index.ts` as a file that would contain all references to the functions and classes. So, no logic in that file.

**functions.ts**

```
export function add(x: number, y: number): number {
  return x + y;
}

export function multiply(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x * y;
}

export function subtract(x:number, y:number): number {
    return x - y;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import * as func from './functions'

var f1 = func.add(2, 5);
console.log('f1 - ' + f1);

var f2 = func.subtract(6, 2);
console.log('f2 - ' + f2);

var f3 = func.multiply(10, 2);
console.log('f3 - ' + f3);

export { func }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "outDir": "src",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "strict": true,
      "module": "ES2015",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')]
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'library.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'library',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
};
```

**New project - script.js**

```
import * as lib from './node_modules/library/dist/library.js'

var a = lib.library.add(2, 9); // -- error, library is not found.
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `umd` library, which aren't as universal as they were when they were named such. You can import them and their code will run but it won't export as intended.

You may want to use a different [library type](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytype) like [`module`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#type-module) (currently experimental and requires enabling, see link for details) or [`commonjs-static`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#type-commonjs-static).

This can be done instead-of or in-addition-to a umd bundle. You can give webpack an array of config object to compile code multiple ways and configure your package.json with [conditional exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#conditional-exports) for different module loaders.

Comment: changing library type to "module" worked for me. Thank you!